# Sources about the Kosher status of Royal Jelly

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, honey

Royal Jelly ("a glandular secretion and its color is a whitish yellow. Its consistency is creamier and less viscous than honey. Its taste is bitter, although not offensively so.") according to [this OU article](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/halachos-of-the-hive/) has different opinions as to it's Kosher status.

> Some have argued that royal jelly should be permitted because it is honey-like, and presumably included in the Scriptural exception as well. But this argument is difficult to support, based on the two reasons cited by the Gemara above. First of all, royal jelly is a glandular secretion, and therefore subject to the general rule of that which comes from an impure (being) is also impure. Also, since it differs in appearance, taste, and function from honey, it should not be included in the Scriptural exception granted to bees’ honey since royal jelly can be considered a totally different food than honey.
>
> Others have contended that royal jelly is not considered fit for human consumption as it is “very bitter” and therefore not subject to any prohibition. This contention, however, is erroneous, for while royal jelly is indeed somewhat tart and bitter, it is by no means inedible even in its pure raw state. This was confirmed by our gentile tester.

Similarly, [this](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3375) Yeshiva.org.il article says:

> There are different approaches in Halacha on this matter.
> Some hold it to be like honey since the Talmud does not differentiate between the two;
> Others hold it to be non Kosher because of your point as it comes from an insect.
> Some are lenient in the case of royal jelly when it’s mixed with honey.
> (See Talmudic Encyclopedia 23 p. 356 and footnotes for the different sources)

Who are the opinions that hold this? (I don't have access to an Encyclopedia Talmudis right now).

So that is four opinions I'm trying to track down.

1. Royal Jelly is like honey and Kosher for the same reason.
2. Royal Jelly is not fit for human consumption.
3. Royal Jelly mixed with honey doesn't forbid keilim or is permitted outright.
4. Royal Jelly mixed with honey *does* forbid keilim or is forbidden outright.

Comment: Any idea what the Hebrew term is for this product in the ET?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no idea.

Comment: A few months ago, one of my friends had me try a spoon of RJ. It tasted so vile that I had to ask her if she had any RPB (royal peanut butter) to go with it to drown out the taste!

Comment: The leniency would be according to the yesh Mi she'oser in siff 9 of the shulchan aruch. That opinion is the Rishonim who pasken like Rabi Yaakov in the gemara who has a gzeiras hakasuv to allow bee honey even if it is ' mimtzi' from the bees body (I.e. royal jelly) . The flip side is that he disallows honey from wasps and grasshoppers. The thing that's bugging me now is that if the amoraim were basing their argument around whether to call honey something that was absorbed vs going in and coming out, the reality of royal jelly should throw the entire sugya through a loop!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encyclopedia Talmudis volume 23 column 356 copied by hand

> יוצא מן הטמא "מזון ממללכות" - כעין דבש שעושת הדבורים, וממנו ניזונית
>   הדבורה "המלכה", היינו זווו שמטילה ביצימ - יש פוסקמי זמננו שאאוסרים
>   אותו, שלדעתם אפשר שהוא מתמצה מגוף הדבורים (945), וכן לדעתם אף לר'
>   יעקוב לא התיר הכתוב אלא דבש סתם, ואין מזון מלכות בכלל (946). ויש
>   מצדדים להתיר (947), שהוא בכלל זו שאמרו:   אבל אתה אוכל מה שעוף טמא
>   משריץ, שאין לו שם לווי כדש הנזים והצרעים, וכמו כן - לדעתם אינו מתמצה
>   מן הגוף (948)
>
> 945 חדושים וביאורים בכורות סי' ב ס"ק ז: קונ' חוקת ישראל לר"א בריזל
>   פ"ו, בסו"ם האנודה קדשים במהדורתו: ספק דאורייתא לחומרא. ןעי' חוברת
>   "מהדרין" ניסן תשנ"ז מרש"ז אוירבך.
>
> 946 חידושים וביאורים שם: חוקת ישראל שם פ"ג באורך, ומפרש שקלה היא שלא
>   הותר אלא דבש סתם, ועי' צון 928
>
> 947 שבט מיהודה ח"א עמ' שמד ואילך שו"ת ציץ אליעזר סי' נט וח"ב סי' נד.
>   ועי"ש ושם שלמעשה לא התירו אלא בצירוף טעמים נוספים, שנאכל בתערובת
>   ולצורך רפואה, ועוד.
>
> 948 ש ושם. ועי' שבט מיהודה שם מכמה מומכים. ועי' אג"מ יו"ד ח"ב סי' כד,
>   שמצד להתיר חומר היוצא מתולעים שנקרא "שעלאק", מפני שאינו מתמצה מגופם,
>   ואף לר' יעקוב יש להתירוו כדבש, כיון שאין מזכירים שם השרץ עליו. עי' צון
>   928, ועי"ש מעמים נוספים להקל.

My translation of the original.

> "Royal Food" - A type of honey that bees produce, which nourishes the
>   "Royal" (queen) bee, which is the one that lays eggs - There are
>   poskim of our time that forbid it, since, according to their analysis,
>   it is produced from the body of the bees (945), And also according to
>   their analysis even according to Rav Ya'akov the pasuk allows only
>   "plain" honey, and not "Royal Food" at all (946).
>
> And there are sides to allow it (947), which is in the general
>   category that states: But you may eat what the nonkoshe bird secretes,
>   because it does not have a spefic name such as "wasp honey" -
>   according to their analysis it is not considered as secreted from the
>   body (948)

Note: The above means that it is considered part of the category "plain honey" since it does not have a specific term of its own. This is also similar to the halachos of hyssop.

From the [star-k](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-Do-Bee-Don't-Bee.htm#_ftn1) we see a psak giving sources.

> Royal Jelly - The most important bee in the hive is the Queen Bee, who
>   attains her "royal" status by her constant extra nutritious diet of
>   royal jelly.  What is royal jelly?  **This product is a secretion from
>   the hypopharyngeal and mandibular glands located in the head of the
>   bee**.  It is rich in protein and vitamins, as well as fatty and amino
>   acids.  Royal jelly is readily available in health food stores, and is
>   a common ingredient in various health food products and remedies. 
>   Because it is a yotzei min hatamei, an actual product that is secreted
>   from the bee, royal jelly should not be eaten.12
>
> 12. Psak of Harav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt”l and Harav Elyashiv zt”l as
>       brought in Bdikas Hamzon K’halacha Chalek HaHalachos Perek 7 Footnote 27.
>       See also Igros Moshe, Y.D. 2:24 – V’gam and Mishna Brura 158:14.

[CRC](http://crc.kosherstar.org/?p=834) gives a similar answer but does not give sources.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_jelly) states

> **Adverse effects**
>
> Royal jelly may cause allergic reactions in humans ranging from hives,
>   asthma, to even fatal anaphylaxis.[11][12][13][14][15][16] The
>   incidence of allergic side effect in people who consume royal jelly is
>   unknown. The risk of having an allergy to royal jelly is higher in
>   people who have other allergies.[11](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9088660)

Answer (score 3):

In an article in the [latest Mesorah journal](https://oukosher.org/content/uploads/2012/12/Mesorah_27.pdf) about shellac, R. Dov Halperin surveys the opinions of the poskim about royal jelly. In short, R. Eliezer Waldenburg, Tzitz Eliezer, and R. Moshe Shternbuch, Teshuvos ve-Hanhagos, permit it for a sick person, and R. Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, Minchas Shlomo, is inclined to forbid it (except for cases of great need). Here is the relevant passage in the article, with the reasoning for each view:

> הציץ אליעזר  מתיר לקחת מזון מלכות לצורך חולה , [כיון שלהלכה פוסקים
>   כדעת ר' יעקב וממילא מכח גזה"כ כל מוצר של הדבורה מותר, וגם לפוסקים
>   כהרמב"ם שסובר שהלכה כדברי חכמים שדבש מותר מפני שאינם ממצות מגופן , מ"מ
>   מזון מלכות נחשב לנסרח ולדעת החוו"ד  בנסרח פקע האיסור ומותר אפילו אם
>   אח"כ חזר ותיקנו].
>
> בספר תשובות והנהגות  מתיר לצורך חולה. טעמי ההיתר א)
>   היוצא מן הטמא אינו אוסר אלא דבר שהוא "מאכל"  כגון "בת היענה", שהוא
>   ביצת היענה וראויה לאכילה, אך דבר שאינו ראוי לאכילה אין מקור לאסור . ב)
>   דעת החוו"ד שאם נסרחה  פקע האיסור גם אם אח"כ מתקן, וכאן עדיף טפי כיון
>   שמעיקרא לא היה ראוי (כמו באפרוחי ביצת טרפה, תמורה דף ל.) . ג) חצי
>   שיעור בתערובת אינו אלא מדרבנן, דחצי שיעור אסור מה"ת רק באיסור גופא אך
>   לא באיסור יוצא שהוא קיל. ובאיסור דרבנן שלא כדרך אכילה לצורך חולה מותר.
>   אלא שמתיר רק אם הוחזק מזון המלכות לרפאות .
>
> המנחת שלמה  מסתפק ונוטה
>   לאסור  דקשה לקבוע מה נקרא סרוח מעיקרא שנפסל מאכילת אדם, שהרי מבואר
>   ברמב"ם  שהיוצא מן החוטם ומן האוזן לא נחשב נפסל מאכילת אדם, שהרי כתב
>   שהם מכשירין לקבל טומאה, ולכאו' הטעם שלהם גרוע ממזון מלכות. אך לענ"ד יש
>   לחלק בין משקה סרוח לבין נבילה סרוחה, דנבילה סרוחה הגדר שאינו ראוי לגר,
>   ואם למשל יקחו חָלב חמוץ שאינו ראוי לגר, מ"מ לענין דין משקין לטומאה
>   שפיר יתכן שיש עליו שם משקה ואינו נחשב סרוח. כי משקין לענין הכשר טומאה
>   אין זה תלוי אם ראוי לאכילת אדם, אלא אם יש על זה שם משקה .

Sources:

> **ציץ אליעזר**
>   חי"א סי' נט.  לחולה שאין בו סכנה וגם מתיר לצורך חיזוק הגוף ולרעננות
>   כוחות נעורים.     ור' זושא יוסף בלעך שליט"א במאמר בקונ' אור ישראל (ניסן
>   תשנ"ט), רצה להוסיף שמזון מלכות אינו נחשב ממצות מגופן אע"פ שלפי חכמי
>   המדע נחשב למיצוי בלוטי, וכמו כן השעוה מותר באכילה והשעללא"ק.
>
> **תשובות והנהגות** ח"ד סי' קפ"ח
>
> **מנחת שלמה**
>   (תנינא) סימן סד.      והתיר רק לחושאב"ס.

Comment: It is always a good idea to translate or summarise sources brought in Lashon haKodesh, as not everyone on this site is literate in it.

Comment: Yes, please provide an English-language translation or summary for the general reader.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Shlomo Amar [allows](http://www.haravamar.org.il/%D7%A9%D7%95-%D7%AA/25-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A9-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95) eating royal jelly (at least when mixed with honey).

Comment: Hi Joseph, welcome to Mi Yodea. My quick read indicates allows it only when mixed with Honey, although he does quote some other more lenient opinions. If you could expand on the answer to pull the sources and the different opinions, this would be a much more solid answer. Thank you for the source.