# Is honeydew (secretion) kosher

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bugs, non-kosher-species, yoreh-deah

[Honeydew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeydew_(secretion)) is a sugar rich  secretion of certain types of bugs. Since these bugs are otherwise non kosher, is this considered non kosher as well, or are they kosher similar to honey?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59691/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OU Kosher brings the following [answer](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/what-is-honeydew-honey-and-is-it-kosher/) to your question

> **Both Rabbi Belsky, zt”l and Rabbi Schachter, ybc”l maintained that
> honeydew honey is not kosher.** This is the case according to both
> opinions cited in the Gemara to allow bee-honey. Chachamim consider
> bee honey as kosher because it is not a secretion of the bee. While
> honeydew honey is the same, nonetheless, the base of the product,
> honeydew, is a non-kosher material, which remains non-kosher even when
> transformed into honey. Rebbi Yaakov derives that honey is kosher from
> a Talmudic exegesis of a verse in Vayikra (11:21). We do not have a
> basis to apply this allowance to honeydew honey, which is the
> byproduct of a non-kosher insect.

Comment: Forgive me if this line of reasoning is entirely outside the rules used here, but wasn't the manna eaten by the Israelites in the desert most likely a honeydew secretion from aphids?  Which would seem to give precedent for eating the secretion of a non-kosher insect.  The book of Exodus does not say that manna came from aphids, of course, but neither is that explanation inconsistent with scripture.

Comment: We don't know what manna was so it cannot be a precedent for honeydew